# mysql não respeita o where de datas utc

Tags: mysql

Estou tentando fazer uma query para retornar os registros de um determinado mes, mas o mysql retorna registros do mes anterior, exemplo:

```
SELECT CREATE_TIME FROM SALE_ORDER WHERE
CREATE_TIME >= ('2016-09-01 00:00:01') AND
CREATE_TIME <= ('2016-09-30 23:59:59') 
ORDER BY CREATE_TIME
```

e ele me retorna:

> 2016-08-31 21:02:19

O banco está na amazon, e o timestamp é utc.

alguma dica?

Comment: Uma dica rápida é você seguir os passos da resposta (aceita) ou da outra para a pergunta (em inglês): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703793/mysql-select-timestamp-column-in-utc-format

Comment: Se preferir, posso postar como resposta a tradução das respostas já existentes no stack gringo. Relacionadas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19023978/should-mysql-have-its-timezone-set-to-utc http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900/how-do-i-set-the-time-zone-of-mysql

Comment: Oi Ismael. 
eu usei esse comando e funcionou na minha local:
CONVERT_TZ(`timestamp_field`, TIMEDIFF(NOW(), UTC_TIMESTAMP), '+00:00') AS `utc_datetime` 

mas quando eu uso na instancia da amazon parece que tem o delay de 3:00.

já tinha lido o post, mas não entendi direito como solucionar.

Comment: ele so funciona se eu colocar na clausula where assim: WHERE
CREATE_TIME >= CONVERT_TZ('2016-09-01 00:00:01', @@session.time_zone, "+03:00") AND
CREATE_TIME <= CONVERT_TZ('2016-09-30 23:59:59', @@session.time_zone, "+03:00") AND

Comment: Force o global time no amazon para `'-3:00'`? `SET GLOBAL time_zone = '-3:00';` para não ter que realizar a conversão em cada registro da sua tabela.

Comment: so o detalhe que esses -3 é agora no horario de verão. e que o timezone no pará também é diferente.

Comment: No Brasil temos 4 fusos: Amazonas -4, Brasília -3 e Fernando de Noronha -2 e o -5 pro Acre. Qual região é a sua?

Comment: tenho clientes acessando o banco de todas as regiões